# Why is Google scripts requiring re-authentication every few hours?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one script file running on a google spreadsheet with 7 custom functions.  One is triggered  via onOpen, 4 are via onEdit, and 2 via custom menu items.  When done editing the script, I do a final save and debug on one of the functions to make sure that the script has been "authenticated".  Reopening the associated spreadsheet works fine for a few hours (both for me and for others who have shared access).  At some point a few hours later, the onOpen script throws an authentication error:

"Authorization is required to perform that action"

and the other functions don't work until I log back in and reauthenticate.

Why would this happen?  I thought re-authentication would only be needed if I make a change to the script.  Is there any way i can debug this so that it stays 'authenticated'?  I need this to work 24/7.

For reference, the various functions hide rows, copy/update cells, delete cell contents, add menu items, calculate dates, etc but nothing too fancy.  One function, currently commented out has a UrlFetchApp line that will pull JSON data from another site.

Thanks,

-BW

Comment: Certainly not behaving like its supposed to. Ive seen recent issues like that in thr gas issues page.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? As @ZigMandel indicated, its not supposed to be behaving this way. I've personally never encountered this issue either.