# How long does a script stay authenticated?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project where I am using scripts to do some calculations and manipulation of data on form submit. Every now and then the script will fail with the following error: `Authorization is required to perform that action.`
I have been unable to find information about this error in the support docs.

2 Questions:

1. How long does my script stay authenticated?
2. Is there a way to automatically re-authenticate or do I just have to manually re-authenticate every time this happens?

Comment: Evidently others have had [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062262/why-is-google-scripts-requiring-re-authentication-every-few-hours).  Personally, I have not.  I think once you authenticate a script it supposed to stay that way until you go into your account and go into secure account and remove access.

Answer (score 2):

*To answer your questions:*

**1. How long does my script stay authenticated?**

Depending on the *publishing status* of your GCP project associated with the script, the authentication will last for different periods of time.

For example, if the publishing status is set to `Testing`, the authentication is set to last for 7 days as a security feature.

> Authorizations by a test user will expire seven days from the time of consent. If your OAuth client requests an offline access type and receives a refresh token, that token will also expire.

Moreover, some other things to take into account regarding deauthorization and the reason behind the error you are receiving:

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.

As pointed out in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177921123) on Public Issue Tracker, a possible solution is to set explicit scopes in the manifest of the Apps Script project. Depending on your use-case, you will have to adjust the ones presented below:

```
 {
    ...
    "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
    ],
   ...
```

**2. Is there a way to automatically re-authenticate or do I just have to manually re-authenticate every time this happens?**

Unfortunately, you *will have to* reauthorize the application manually each time.

#### Reference

- [Setting Up Your OAuth Consent Screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctesting);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration);
- [Public Issue Tracker Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177921123);
- [Apps Script Authorization Scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).